# How to find document.activeElement in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, autofill, webautomation

i want to autofill a form with puppeteer. 
I fill out the first input, then click on a button that then creates a new input field that has focus.

How can i select this input? Can i use document.activeElement and how?

```
  let newActivity = 'button.new_activity'
  await page.waitForSelector(newActivity)
  await page.click(newActivity)

// find active/focused input
await page.type(focusedInput, 'message')
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `evaluateHandle` to get the element handle, and then call the `type` function on that element.

```js
const el = await page.evaluateHandle(() => document.activeElement);
await el.type('message');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function findFocusedNode(node) {
    if (node.focused) {
        return node;
    }

    for (const child of node.children || []) {
        const focusedNode = findFocusedNode(child);
        if (focusedNode) {
            return focusedNode;
        }
    }
}

const snapshot = await page.accessibility.snapshot();
const focusedNode = findFocusedNode(snapshot);
console.log('focusedNode', focusedNode);
```

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-accessibility